# IDEA cannot re-import sbt project

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

It happens often with current stable version of (Community) IDEA (2021.1.2) and Scala plugin (2021.1.21) that I make changes under Windows on an sbt file (sbt version 1.5.3 for example), IDEA shows that it needs to import, but it fails with:

> Extracting structure failed, reason: not ok build status: Error (BuildMessages(Vector(),Vector(),Vector(),Vector(),Error))

The sbt files are correct (also the error message is not very helpful).
I also have sbt shell running, though it is not executing anything.

Here is the sbt related configuration of IDEA (Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | sbt):
[image: IDEA settings for sbt]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-19190

Answer (score 44):

> I also have sbt shell running, though it is not executing anything.

This is the problem. When sbt shell is not used for project reload, it prevents importing the project.

The possible solutions include stopping the sbt shell during the import or change the setting "Build, Execution, Deployment" | "Build Tools" | "sbt" | "sbt projects" | "sbt shell" | "use for:" | "project reload" to be checked.

[image: project reload to be enabled]

Comment: Although the sbt shell has its own problem on Windows: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-15337 (feel free to vote for it)